# How do I uninstall Ubuntu 14 and reinstall Windows 8? I only have product key

Tags: system-installation

I installed Ubuntu 14 a day ago, overwriting my Windows. Now I want to switch Ubuntu back to Windows 8 using a product key that I have in an email.

How do you do this? So far I have had no luck.

Comment: And you have no installation media on dvd/usb/disk?

Answer (score 0):

I you have overwritten your windows, You need to install Windows again on your PC. You can note down the product key and after insert media to install windows. You cant retrive deleted files just by a product key.

Comment: Im having a hard time understanding exactly what you mean